# Multiply each row using Arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, multidimensional-array, transpose, google-query-language

In Google Sheets, I have the following data:

```
   |   A |  B  |  C  |  ...  | G  | TOTALS   
 1 |  100|  200|  400|  ...  | 870| =PRODUCT(A1:G1)  |
 2 |  120|  240|  360|  ...  | 232| =PRODUCT(A2:G2)  |
 3 |  125|  425|  100|  ...  | 509| =PRODUCT(A3:G3)  |
```

How can I create the TOTALS column using ARRAYFORMULA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shorter and should be faster (with some tweaking for sure):

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/DPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE({A1:A*0, A1:G}), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A)), {IF(,,); IF(,,)}))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/QUERY(QUERY(
 IF(LEN(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:G10),,9^9)))), 
 IF(A1:G10="", 1, A1:G10*1), 0), 
 "select Col"&JOIN("*Col", COLUMN(A:G))), 
 "offset 1", 0))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

or simply:

```
=INDEX(A:A * B:B * C:C * D:D * E:E * F:F * G:G)
```

[image]